# Heroku postgres query only returns rows created by node app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have a node app running postgres, hosted in Heroku. If I run the following query to an empty table called 'searches' with an auto increment 'id' and 'term' columns, via my DB admin tool:

```
insert into searches ("term") values ('value added direct to db');
```

In the node app, I then run some code which sends the following query to the DB:

```
insert into searches ("term") values ('value added via app');
```

If I run the following in my DB admin tool:

```
select * from searches;
```

I get exactly what you'd think, something like:

```
id     term
1      value added direct to db
2      value added via app
```

Here's where I get utterly confused. The same select * query run via the app returns this:

```
id     term
2      value added via app
```

I'm new to both Heroku and postgres, but this makes zero sense to me. How is it that the Heroku app can't return a record added manually to the DB? Is there something really weird about the Heroku environment that isn't explicit in their tutorials?

Just to save questions - there is no mix-up with environments (ie. I think I'm running the query on the same DB, but actually one is production, and another dev). I know this because there is only 1 DB, and I can watch the rows being created by the two different routes.

Comment: Just to make sure... in your previous question your node code's query had a `LIMIT 1` on it, but the query in this question doesn't? And if you've removed the `LIMIT`, does re-adding it result in zero rows returned?

Comment: No - it makes no affect. There's nothing really relevant to limit 1 in the above - if I do the process above multiple times, the select * in the app returns row 2,4,6... whereas run from my DB admin it will give all rows as expected.

Comment: OK... adding to issue. I tried to start from scratch with this part of the code, so I deleted the searches table, and recreated it. Ran the code again, and now Heroku doesn't even think the table exists, and I get "error: relation "searches" does not exist" logged. It does exist - I can query it via the DB. Can anyone explain Heroku to me!?!?

Comment: Wait... I think I have an idea. Are things I'm running via my DB editor being put into transactions that are never getting committed? This could explain the behaviour. Can anybody tell me what I'm not doing correctly (as I say - new to postgres)

Comment: OK... that's it. If I run 'COMMIT;' every time I do something in my DB editor, everything works.